# Moving from notebook to pipeline replicating the generic datascience kernel from notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

What would I need to do to replicate the data science kernel as an amazon image. I'm confused as it [says](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-now-supports-amazon-linux-2/#:%7E:text=SageMaker%20notebook%20instances%20use%20AMIs,AMI%20(Amazon%20Linux%202).) the base image for notebook is a deep learning container but I don't think that will have all the packages installed on the deep learning kernel. Is there an easy way to replicate this environment or work out what it is? It's really difficult to work out what versions of what packages to install to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

The build-in Studio [Kernels](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebooks-available-kernels.html) (Conda based) and [SageMaker Deep Learning containers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/pre-built-containers-frameworks-deep-learning.html) should be very similar for a given framework version, but I don't think they are 100% exact.

To have the exact same container (not an AMI) for your SageMaker Studio notebook and outside of the notebook, you can use the [bring your own image in SageMaker Studio](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-byoi.html).
Note that this is for SageMaker Studio Notebooks, not a SageMaker notebook instance ([compare](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebooks-comparison.html)).

Comment: Thanks for your help! Do you happen to know where to find the kernels? It just says that they're kernels with common packages installed but no where to get the actual kernel. Thanks.

Comment: To tell what's in a kernel, Open a Studio notebook, pick a kernel and inspect the installed packages with a `conda list` command, and perhaps the equivilant in `pip`.